# Press a button on an EXTERNAL window (another application)

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage

I want to press a button of an external window (a game table). Usually I use without problems  SendMessage, but this specific window accepts SendMessage **only if the mouse is over it**.

Since I don't want the cursor moves to the window when the monitoring routine finds a button to press, I have made this code:

```
        'X and Y are the coordinates of the point to press
        Dim lParam As IntPtr = MakeLong(X, Y)

        'block of the cursor (for few milliseconds)
        Cursor.Clip = New Rectangle(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 1, 1)
        'I move the mouse over the button
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(TableHwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, lParam)
        Sleep(30)
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(TableHwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, lParam)
        Sleep(40)
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(TableHwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam)
        'release of the cursor
        Cursor.Clip = Rectangle.Empty
```

This code WORKS PERFECTLY **if the mouse cursor is OUT of the window**: the button is pressed without the window gets focus. The cursor does'nt move.

If when I must press the button the cursor is OVER the window **the above code presses only under the cursor** (i.e. another button !!) **ignoring lParam**. Why?????